# HtmlHelper library in java - source not found

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Help me please to found an error in my java-method onItemClick. When I comment all code in try-catch construction - the program runs, but in otherwise - program crashes with error "Source not found". I prefer, the error starts up with **hh = new HtmlHelper(new URL((String)** url)) string.

```
@Override
                   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg) 
                   {
                      String stringData;
                      Intent intent = new Intent(StackParser.this, AvailableContent.class);
                      url = (String) mURLs.get(output.get(position));
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      HtmlHelper hh;
                      try 
                      {
                        hh = new HtmlHelper(new URL((String) url));
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
                        List<TagNode> links = hh.getLinksByClass("texts");
                        Iterator<TagNode> iterator = links.iterator();
                        iterator.hasNext();
                        TagNode divElement = (TagNode) iterator.next();
                        stringData = divElement.getText().toString();
                        if(!stringData.equals(""))
                        {
                            intent.putExtra("Send to the content-activity", stringData);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            intent.putExtra("Send to the content-activity", "empty");
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }
                      } 
                      catch (MalformedURLException e) 
                      {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                      } 
                      catch (IOException e) 
                      {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                      }
                      catch (InterruptedException e) 
                      {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                      }
                   }
                });
```

Comment: I could not get logcat, but in debug mode I get a message "Source not found The source attachement does not contain the source fot the file BaseDexClassLoader.class"

Comment: my first suggestion to you is to work on your logcat. Without it you are like a blind man trying to cross new york traffic

Comment: based on the given information.. looks like there is a mistake in the intent. Shouldn't it be `Intent intent = new Intent(this, AvailableContent.class);` instead of `Intent intent = new Intent(StackParser.this, AvailableContent.class);` ?

Comment: No..Thanks, but no.Error